# Prolog - functional term vs predicate

Tags: prolog

What is the difference between **functional term** from **predicate** in prolog ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I can remember correctly:

A functional term is a type of *term* that looks like pred_name(...). The *parser* deals with terms, which also include constants and variables.

A predicate is not the name of the thing, but the thing itself; something which is either true or false. Functional terms are used to define and call predicates.

So, strictly speaking, terms don't succeed or fail, and you can't parse predicates. It is much like the difference between a numeral and a number.

Comment: what's the difference between a numeral and a number :-P

Comment: @cjds here is the answer https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=difference+between+a+numeral+and+a+number&rlz=1C5CHFA_enJP727JP727&oq=difference+between+a+numeral+and+a+number&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.365j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I include the text from the previous link so this answer is self-contained. "A numeral is a symbol or name that stands for a number. Examples: 3, 49 and twelve are all numerals. So the number is an idea, the numeral is how we write it.". See also [What is the difference between 'number' and 'numeral'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/392716/162513)