# In prolog, functors vs predicates, and goals

Tags: prolog

I am beginning to learn Prolog. I have various books and I even bought the standard. I like things like standards because they define things precisely. But I can't understand some concepts. In particular the difference between functors and predicates, and what is a goal exactly ? Typically the books use a terminology which is varying and sometimes not precise enough adding to the confusion.

In the standard a predication is defined as "a predicate with arity N and a sequence of N arguments" and a predicate as "an identifier together with an arity". Thus when they write something like `father(Father, Child)` in The Art of Prolog 2nd, they call `father/2` a predicate.

OK but when I check the syntax, we talk about compound terms (not predicates or predications) which are formed of a functor name and arguments. So I checked the definitions in the Standard and saw that a functor is "an identifier together with an arity", the same definition as predicate, and a compound term as "a functor of arity N, N positive, together with a sequence of N arguments".

Thus what is the relation between functors and predicates ? Syntactically they look the same. Why `father(Father, Child)` couldn't be called a compound term (I guess it is indeed, syntactically) with functor `father/2` instead of predicate `father/2` ? When do we use one terminology or the other ?

And to put the cherry on top, a goal is "a predication which is to be executed". Do we talk about goals inside the Prolog program or only in the query ? In The Art of Prolog, it is written that "goals are atoms or compound terms". Thus could we talk about goals everywhere in the Prolog program ? My readings make me feel that it is used in the query only. But I'm not sure.

In a query, I guess `mother(X, Y)` is a goal and `mother/2` a predicate but is `mother(X, Y), male(Y)` a goal ? Or composed of two goals ? It is said that a goal can be an atom or a compound term. But if we look at `,` in functional notation then we have a compound term and then a single goal composed of two sub-goals ? I don't understand.

To put it briefly, I don't know when to call things predicate (predication), functor (compound term) or goal.

**EDIT**

Having read the comments, the answer and other questions ([28972038](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28972038) and [15807506](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15807506)), I came to the conclusion that we have a situation similar to the one in Lisp-like languages : the same notation is used for "executable" code and data. Thus everything is written as terms and a lot of them are compound terms which involves functors and arguments. This is the syntax of data. And the same syntax is used for clauses (facts and rules) which compose a Prolog program. We talk about functors when we focus on the data side of things and predicates when we focus on the "executable" (or interpretable ) side of things, the meaning of the logic program. The focus in question usually depends on the context in which the constructs are used.

Comment: One of the most interesting and useful things about Prolog is that clauses (= rules and facts) have a *natural representation as Prolog terms*. For example, a Prolog rule *is* a Prolog term, with functor `:-/2` and two arguments: head and body. Both head and body are again Prolog terms. In addition, I would like to add that `father/2` is a pretty ambiguous name for a predicate with two arguments: `father_child/2` would be much better, because it makes clear what the arguments actually mean.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find it when looking for similar questions

Comment: One thing still wrong in your description is the role of *functors*: A functor is always part of a term. If you are ever unsure about the exact form of your terms, use `write_canonical/1` in ISO-compliant Prolog systems to see the canonical syntax of a term. For example: `?- write_canonical(my_rule(X, Y) :- father_child(X, Y)).`, yielding: `:-(my_rule(A,B),father_child(A,B))`.

Comment: What is specifically wrong with the description ? AFAIK, a functor is always part of a compound term, not necessarily a term. The other terms are atomic terms and variables where functors are not involved. You mean that an operator like `:-` is in fact a functor and can be written using the functional notation `:-( ... )` ?

Comment: You repeatedly mention "functors and predicates", where you mean *terms* and predicates. I only want to emphasize that functors are always *part* of a term. So, when you regard predicates as data, you regard their clauses as (compound or atomic) *terms*.

Comment: Yes, thanks. In my EDIT I wrote "We talk about functors when we focus on the data side of things" which is wrong and you were right to point that I should have written "terms" which include functors and their arguments.

Comment: @lurker please seriously reconsider this view: `foo`, `bar`, `bah` are all *atoms*, which are clearly terms.

Comment: @mat thanks. Yes, sorry, that was my misunderstanding. I did find definitions [here](http://www.dai.ed.ac.uk/groups/ssp/bookpages/quickprolog/node5.html), which make that clear. My view of the meaning of *term* was too narrow.

Comment: Relatedly, I would also like to mention that *atoms* nicely fit this classification as terms with arity 0, and whose functor is the respective atom itself. Therefore, the **exercise**: Find all cases where *compound term* is used redundantly *or* incorrectly *or* its use is needlessly limiting or complicating the cases under consideration in the original text, the edit and the comments.

Comment: Yes we could but the standard distinguishes between atoms and compound terms (which have a functor). Anyway, I think that it could be an interesting point of view to consider atoms having arity 0.

Comment: Atoms are *not* compound terms, but both atoms and compound terms are terms! Therefore, you can simplifiy some of your statements above, and in some cases "compound term" is simply too limiting: For example, a goal need not have any arguments at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to explain this to my students in the following way: What is `father(X,Y)` in the following cases (independent from the missing context...)?

```
?- isA(father(X,Y)).
```

and

```
?- father(X,Y).
```

In the first case, it's the `father` functor that constructs a binary term, in the second case, it's a binary predicate.

The confusion (that they look the same) is also used actively when you go beyond plain Prolog and to things like:

```
?- X = father, X(tim,john).
```

or using `father/2` in a `findall` query.

Comment: I think that your answer plus the comment by @mat and the question [Prolog - functional term vs predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807506/prolog-functional-term-vs-predicate) answer the question. I will edit the question to add my current understanding

Comment: What is the context for `?- X = father, X(tim,john).` This line always throws out error on my machine...