# what is the difference between a predicate and a functor in prolog?

Tags: prolog

The following is an example of prolog.

```
likes(mary,X) :- yellow(X).
```

According to the definitions I've found (LPN, Bratko, AoP) the `likes` fits the definition of a **predicate** and a **functor**.

`yellow` also fits the definitions. If the clause were a simple fact (empty body), eg `yellow(banana).` , that would appear to make no difference.

**Question:** What is the difference between a **predicate** and a **functor**, in the context of prolog, if any?

Comment: the answer to this seems genuinely helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807506/prolog-functional-term-vs-predicate

Answer (score 1):

*functor* is used to describe terms syntactically: `likes(mary,X)` is a term that has an arity of 2 and a primary functor `likes`. The functor is written `likes/2` because it is a couple of a name and an arity. Note that `likes/2` is also a term, written in an infix way:

```
?- functor(likes(a,b),F,A).
F = likes,
A = 2.

?- functor(likes/2,F,A).
F =  (/),
A = 2.
```

An atom is a term of arity 0:

```
?- functor(banana, F, A).
F = banana,
A = 0.
```

Now, terms in Prolog can be used to describe data or to define procedures.  When you write `S = person(Name, Age)`, the functor of S is `person/2`, it is not *ground* because it contains unbound variables. By itself, it is just a data structure. However, you can also try to call it in a query:

```
?- S = person(Name, Age), call(S).
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
?- person(Name, Age).
```

But unless you defined such a predicate, you will encounter an error.

You can write predicates as follows in your source code:

```
person(Name, Age) :- 
   date_of_birth(Name, Date), 
   age_now(Date, Age).
```

The body of the clause can also be trivially true:

```
person(john, 20) :- true.
```

In which case it is a fact, also written:

```
person(john, 20).
```

See also [`term`](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Ebillw/dictionaries/prolog/term.html) from [The Prolog Dictionary](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Ebillw/dictionaries/prolog/).

Comment: Hi @coredump - thanks for this - so to be totally clear, it is correct to say`likes` is both a functor and a predicate? The difference is the context - functor is about syntax, predicate is about relations/meaning/definition, yes?

Comment: Yes, but usually you have to provide the arity because `likes/1` and `likes/2` can be different predicate with the same name but different arities.